# Create hourly/minutely time range using pandas

Tags: python, time, pandas, range

Is there a way to generate time range in pandas similar to `date_range`?
Something like:

```
pandas.time_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min")
```

Comment: On a single specific date (use [`pandas.DataFrame.between_time()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), or a range of dates, or unattached to a date?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A time range doesn't exist as a standalone index type. Generate using a single date

```
In [1]: pandas.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min")
Out[1]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-07-14 11:00:00, ..., 2013-07-14 21:30:00]
Length: 22, Freq: 30T, Timezone: None
```

The time objects

```
In [2]: pandas.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min").time
Out[2]: 
array([datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(11, 30), datetime.time(12, 0),
       datetime.time(12, 30), datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(13, 30),
       datetime.time(14, 0), datetime.time(14, 30), datetime.time(15, 0),
       datetime.time(15, 30), datetime.time(16, 0), datetime.time(16, 30),
       datetime.time(17, 0), datetime.time(17, 30), datetime.time(18, 0),
       datetime.time(18, 30), datetime.time(19, 0), datetime.time(19, 30),
       datetime.time(20, 0), datetime.time(20, 30), datetime.time(21, 0),
       datetime.time(21, 30)], dtype=object)
```

You can also resample if you are spanning multiple dates.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I am trying to count occurrences of events in duration in say 10 minute bins.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be looking for `pd.timedelta_range()`:

```py
pd.timedelta_range("11:00:00", "21:30:00", freq="30min")

TimedeltaIndex(['0 days 11:00:00', '0 days 11:30:00', '0 days 12:00:00',
                '0 days 12:30:00', '0 days 13:00:00', '0 days 13:30:00',
                '0 days 14:00:00', '0 days 14:30:00', '0 days 15:00:00',
                '0 days 15:30:00', '0 days 16:00:00', '0 days 16:30:00',
                '0 days 17:00:00', '0 days 17:30:00', '0 days 18:00:00',
                '0 days 18:30:00', '0 days 19:00:00', '0 days 19:30:00',
                '0 days 20:00:00', '0 days 20:30:00', '0 days 21:00:00',
                '0 days 21:30:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq='30T')
```