# How to make a pandas series whose index is every day of 2020

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make an empty pandas series with a date index which is every day of 2020.  That is 01-01-2020, 02-01-2020 etc.

Although this looks very simple I couldn’t find out how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create hourly/minutely time range using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644100/create-hourly-minutely-time-range-using-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `date_range`:

```
range_2020 = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", freq="D")
pd.DataFrame(range(366), index=range_2020)
```

The output is:

```
              0
2020-01-01    0
2020-01-02    1
2020-01-03    2
2020-01-04    3
2020-01-05    4
...
```