# List of DateTime with time-step

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I have a list of timing for the appointment but I couldn't divide the time into 15-minute steps. This is what I want to achieve.

Time: 6 AM - 8AM to this format: 06:00 -> 06: 15 -> 06:30 -> 06:45-> 07:00 and so on.
I tried but couldn't do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644100/create-hourly-minutely-time-range-using-pandas

Comment: @edhaussy that is according to pandas framework in python. I want an answer related to dart language.

Comment: Do you want a list of DateTime objects where the date is today and the time goes from 6AM to 8AM?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```dart
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
DateTime first = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 6); // today 6AM
final numberOfSlots = 2 * 4 + 1; // 2 hours * 4 (15 minutes) + 1 to go from 6 to 8
final list = List.generate(
  numberOfSlots,
  (index) => first.add(Duration(minutes: index * 15)),
);
print(list);
```

Comment: Don't do your math in localtime if you might be crossing a DST boundary.  Instead, do your math in utc, and then convert back.